# Is there a way to refresh contents of a kendo window after a set time has passed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-window

So I have a main page that loads in various forms buttons, clicking one of those buttons triggers a kendo window to be opened and its content come from another form loaded in via jquery. The user can have multiple kendo windows open but only one for each button. So 3 buttons, means the user can have a maximum 3 kendo windows open. Problem is the contents of the forms in the kendo windows are based off of SQL data that is fetched in the Page_Load event in code-behind. After a few minutes passes I want the kendo windows to refresh with any changes in the data from the SQL database.  The kendo window has a refresh button that does exactly what I want to do, however that has to be manually triggered, and I want the updates to be triggered based off of a timer.

Ive already tried using

```
SetInterval($("#myid").data("kendowindow").refresh(),10000)
```

but that gives me an invalid viewstate error. Ive tried adding an update timer in the form itself that is called in via jquery but that reloads the whole page not just the kendo window.

Comment: How do you initially load the content of your Kendo window? If you do it via ajax, a refresh should re-get the (now new) content via ajax

Comment: @Jonathan , i have each button click trigger a jquery function that creates a kendo window and simply set the content of the kendo window to my asp.net form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys I am one giant idiot, JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ARE CASE SENSITIVE!.

final code was

```
        setInterval(function (e) { $("#myid").data("kendoWindow").refresh() }, 5000);
```